# CRC 16 code with "unsafe features"

Tags: c#, performance

I have the following CRC 16 code.  Is it possible to improve the performance of the code with unsafe constructs?  My knowledge about pointer arithmetic is rather limited.

```
public enum Crc16Mode : ushort { Standard = 0xA001, CcittKermit = 0x8408 }

public class Crc16Ccitt
{
    static ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    public ushort ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    public Crc16Ccitt(Crc16Mode mode)
    {
        ushort polynomial = (ushort)mode;
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the performance of this code problematic? `ComputeChecksum` looks rock-solid as you can get. The only other improvement I can see is to remove the constructor and replace with an already-computed table such as this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074468/3312

Comment: Thanks. Thats one improvement i will do. I am just curious if there would be any major performance gain when using "unsafe features". Also for learning about this subject by example.

Comment: One obvious issue is that your code is incorrect. You have one static table, but there are two kinds of CRC calculator you can instantiate. If you instantiate instances of both of them, your program becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks pretty good except for the `static table`. More about that later.

Unsafe code has a few things that can make code go faster, like pointers to arrays and arrays on the stack.

A pointer to array would make code only faster if the code is iterating through that array. `ComputeChecksum` does iterate trough `data`, so yes, this part could become a little bit faster. We are talking about microseconds.

You are also iterating through an the table array inside the constructor. So creation of this table could also become a littel bit faster.

Personally: I would not use unsafe code in your case.

**About the static**

You have a static table, but when you create a new instance of `Crc16Ccitt` it will recalculate all the (same) values. (Talking about performance loss!) If you have two instances of `Crc16Ccitt` with different polynomials, then one of your instances will calculate it CRC's wrong, because they both share the same table (since it is static).

How to solve this in a faster and safer way?

Use a static! (Huh?) Yes, a static but another one:

`static private readonly Dictionary<Crc16Mode, ushort[]> _tables;` This will store all calculated tables.

In your class use a local field: `ushort[] _table;` This one will hold the (already) calculated table. If the table was not calculated, it will be calculated and stored inside `_tables`.

You also use this mechanism to store hard coded calcaulated tables, as Jesse suggests. In that case you would assign your hard code table to the dictionary inside a static constructor.

Your code could become like this:

```
public enum Crc16Mode : ushort { Standard = 0xA001, CcittKermit = 0x8408 }

public class Crc16Ccitt
{
    #region Static members

    static private readonly Dictionary<Crc16Mode, ushort[]> _tables = new Dictionary<Crc16Mode, ushort[]>();

    static private ushort[] GetTable(Crc16Mode mode)
    {
        lock (_tables)
        {
            ushort[] table;
            if (_tables.TryGetValue(mode, out table))
                return table;

            ushort polynomial = (ushort)mode;
            for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
            {
                ushort value = 0;
                ushort temp = i;
                for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                {
                    if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                        value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                    else
                        value >>= 1;
                    temp >>= 1;
                }
                table[i] = value;
            }
            _tables[mode] = table;
            return table;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly ushort[] _table = new ushort[256];

    public Crc16Ccitt(Crc16Mode mode)
    {
        _table = GetTable(mode);
    }

    public ushort ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ _table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried to do

```
public ushort ComputeChecksumUnsafe(params byte[] bytes)
{
    ushort crc = 0;
    unsafe
    {
        int len = bytes.Length;
        fixed (byte* pb = bytes)
        {
            fixed (ushort* tab = table)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                {
                    byte index = (byte)(crc ^ pb[i]);
                    crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ tab[index]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Unfortunately, even with 100Mbytes data the performance is still the same with safe version. I just post this FYI.